# Why do I get expected type `()` when trying to obtain a reference to a boxed value?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have this struct:

```
pub struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn getLeft(&self) -> Option<&Self> {
        if self.left.is_some() {
            Some(&(*(self.left.unwrap())))
            // Some(self.left.unwrap()) <= same result
        }
        None
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

There seems to be a type mismatch as I get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:13
   |
10 |             Some(&(*(self.left.unwrap())))
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected (), found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected type `()`
              found type `std::option::Option<&Node<T>>`
```

I'm new to Rust and don't understand why the expected type is `()` while it should be `Option<&Self>` and how can I return a reference to the node inside the box (how can I move out of borrowed self)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here isn't the borrow-checker.  If you have an `if` without an `else`, you *must* return unit (*i.e.* `()`).  You're trying to return a value from the function, which means you need to either have an `else` branch, or use `return`.  To wit:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn getLeft(&self) -> Option<&Self> {
        if self.left.is_some() {
            Some(&(*(self.left.unwrap())))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, *now* the borrow-checker is a problem.  This is because you're taking a reference to a temporary (the result of `self.left.unwrap()`).  You need to access the contents of the `Option` *without* moving it.  So let's do that:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn getLeft(&self) -> Option<&Self> {
        if self.left.is_some() {
            Some(&(*(self.left.as_ref().unwrap())))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

That's better, but it's just ugly.  There's the `unwrap`, plus the redundant parentheses, the name is non-idiomatic, and finally the whole branch itself is unnecessary.  Let's fix all of those:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn get_left(&self) -> Option<&Self> {
        self.left.as_ref().map(|l| &**l)
    }
}
```

Or, if you want something slightly clearer:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn get_left(&self) -> Option<&Self> {
        if let Some(left) = self.left.as_ref() {
            Some(&**left)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because the `if` block is an expression; you need to follow it with an `else` so that the output of the function is correct (`Option<&Self>`).

In addition, you can utilize `if let` to obtain the inner value of an `Option`; then it is easy to get the reference out of the `Box`:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn getLeft(&self) -> Option<&Self> {
        if let Some(ref left) = self.left { // if let
            Some(&*left) // return a reference to the content of the Box (in an Option)
        } else {
            None // or return None if self.left is None
        }
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
fn main() {
    let test0 = Node {
        value: 0,
        left: None,
        right: None
    };

    let test1 = Node {
        value: 0,
        left: Some(Box::new(test0)),
        right: None
    };

    println!("{:?}", test1.getLeft()); // Some(Node { value: 0, left: None, right: None })
}
```